# Calculating eigenvalue without rigorous calculation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the given matrix $A$ then show that $20-\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue.

\begin{bmatrix}
   40 & -29 & -11\\
   -18 & 30 & -12\\
    26 & 24 & -50
  \end{bmatrix}

So I observed that the columns are linearly dependent in fact $C_1+C_3=-C_2$. I am not quite sure how to proceed. I am a little unclear as to how matrix operations effect the eigenvalues. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints**:

The columns are linearly dependent, therefore one of the eigenvalues is equal to _____

The sum of all eigenvalues of a matrix is equal to _____